# Ubuntu Server 16.04.5 installed with Apache loads Laravel application as plain text

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5

I have deployed Laravel 5.5 application on Ubuntu Server and I keep getting plain text when I load the index.php in public folder of my application. I think there is something wrong with the server configuration or I might be missing an extension or dependency. Any help please.

Comment: Is PHP installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP code is not being executed, instead code shows on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121495/php-code-is-not-being-executed-instead-code-shows-on-the-page)

Comment: Yes, I have php 7 installed.